# How do i join these two PSQL queries together correctly?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to return a query that will show how many times a player has played in a game and how many time he/she has won. This is what I have so far, stuck on the last join query

Link to my SQL fiddle: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/46b2a/52

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE player(
id serial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
name varchar(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE match(
id serial PRIMARY KEY,
winner serial REFERENCES player(id) NOT NULL,
loser serial REFERENCES player(id) NOT NULL CHECK (loser != winner)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE playerid_sequence 
start 1
increment 1;

CREATE SEQUENCE matchid_sequence
start 1
increment 1;
```

I populated my tables with some example insertions:

```
--Player Insertion 
INSERT INTO player VALUES(nextval('playerid_sequence'), 'Kevin');
INSERT INTO player VALUES(nextval('playerid_sequence'), 'Dennis');
INSERT INTO player VALUES(nextval('playerid_sequence'), 'George');
INSERT INTO player VALUES(nextval('playerid_sequence'), 'Michael');

--Match Insertion
INSERT INTO match VALUES(nextval('matchid_sequence'), 1, 2);
INSERT INTO match VALUES(nextval('matchid_sequence'), 1, 3);
INSERT INTO match VALUES(nextval('matchid_sequence'), 1, 4);
INSERT INTO match VALUES(nextval('matchid_sequence'), 2, 3);
```

I created two SQL queries:

```
--How many did a player win?
SELECT player.id, player.name, count(player.name) as wins FROM player, match 
WHERE player.id = match.winner GROUP by player.name, player.id ORDER BY wins DESC;

--How many matches did a particular player participate in?
SELECT player.id, player.name, count(player.name) as matches_played
FROM player, match
WHERE player.id = match.winner OR player.id = match.loser 
GROUP by player.name, player.id
ORDER by matches_played DESC;
```

I made an attempt to join them:

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM
(SELECT player.id, player.name, count(player.name) as wins FROM player, match 
WHERE player.id = match.winner GROUP by player.name, player.id ORDER BY wins DESC) t1 
FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT player.id as id, count(player.name) as matches_played
FROM player, match
WHERE player.id = match.winner OR player.id = match.loser 
GROUP by player.id
ORDER by matches_played DESC) t2
ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

The above join query only returns the set of players from t1, while I want it to return all of the players from t2.

I want:
player id| name| wins| total matches played for all the players, with 0's in the win column if they haven't won.

I have:

```
 id name    wins    id  matches_played
 1  Kevin   3       1    3
 2  Dennis  1       2    2
 (null) (null)  (null)  4   1
 (null) (null)  (null)  3   2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the query can be simplified to:

```
select p.id, p.name,
       count(case when m.winner = p.id then 'X' end) as wins,
       count(m.id) as matches_played
  from player p
  left join match m
    on m.winner = p.id or m.loser = p.id
 group by p.id, p.name;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3a787/4)

The key is that you want to left join on the `match` table.  The rest is simple conditional aggregation.